# How to add columns and tables automatically when importing sql phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import database of my website to the new vps. But since i have done lots of modifications,there fore created lots of tables, and columns in existing tables other than the default every time i try to upload the sql i get error like 'unknown column xxx', or 'table xxx not exist'.
and other issue is unfortunately my sql backup doesnt have the 'create table if not exist' queries.so getting the errors like 'table xxx not exist'.
so in this condition what i can do so than i need not add the required tables and columns manually to perform successfull upload.
and its opencart script which is my website using.

Comment: can you make a new mysqldump from the table without data to get the create informations. Sequel Pro on Mac has some features to import (CSV) data in new tables.

Comment: i got old backup with create information after lots of search .. anyway thanks for replying.. :)